# Calling a javascript function from another .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two external .js files. The first contains a function. The second calls the function.

file1.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function menuHoverStart(element, topshift, thumbchange) {

        ... function here ...

    } 

});
```

file2.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(function() { menuHoverStart("#myDiv", "63px", "myIMG"); },2000); 

});
```

The trouble is that this is not running the function. I need the two separate files because file2.js is inserted dynamically depending on certain conditions.  This function works if I include the setTimeout... line at the end of file1.js

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `menuHoverStart` declared in the global scope?

Comment: possibly not - how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The problem is, that `menuHoverStart` is not accessible outside of its scope (which is defined by the `.ready()` callback function in file #1). You need to make this function available in the global scope (or through any object that is available in the global scope):

```
function menuHoverStart(element, topshift, thumbchange) {
    // ...
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // ...
});
```

If you want `menuHoverStart` to stay in the `.ready()` callback, you need to add the function to the global object manually (using a function expression):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.menuHoverStart = function (element, topshift, thumbchange) {
        // ...
    };
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You have declared `menuHoverStart` inside a function (the anonymous one you pass to the ready ready). That limits its scope to that function and you cannot call it from outside that function.

It doesn't *do* anything there, so there is no need to hold off on defining it until the ready event fires, so you could just move it outside the anonymous function.

That said, globals are worth avoiding, so you might prefer to define a namespace (to reduce the risk of name collisions) and hang the function off that.

```
var MYNAMESPACE = {}; // In the global scope, not in a function
// The rest can go anywhere though
MYNAMESPACE.menuHoverStart = function (element, topshift, thumbchange) {
```