# Why do I have to refresh my page for a javascript function to work?

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a mobile site and using jQuery.

When I load a certain page and click the desired button, the code does not execute until I refresh the page. Why is this ?

Here's how I have it

```
script.js

$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
  $("#user-save").click(
      function(e)
       {
         alert(/clickity-click/);
       });
});

page.php

<html>
   <head>
       <!-- Other jQuery files here -->
      <script src="script.js"></script>
   </head>
<body>
   <div id="user-save" data-role="button">Click me like a boss</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check for pop-up blocker on ur browser.

Comment: Even on Internet Explorer 7 the behavior is the same. IE7 which allows popups by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery Mobile loads pages differently from a 'normal' javascript application. You will typically need to bind to the pageinit event instead of document.ready.

See [this previous SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622581/jquery-mobile-document-ready-equivalent) on this topic

Answer (score 3):

I spent several hours rewriting the code on a page that was having this problem, only to realize that the problem was related to the linking/previous page.

The anchor tag and link on the linking/previous page, the one that leads to the page where you would like to ensure `$(document).ready(init)` will run, needs to have to include `data-ajax="false"` attribute like this:

```
<a href="yourpage.html" data-ajax="false">
```

This will ensure that JQuery Mobile doesn't expect that you're loading content dynamically with AJAX, and you are in fact navigating to a different/new page. In other words, JQuery Mobile will only run the `$(document).ready()` if it is loading a different/new page.

Comment: Thanks. The question was already answered by @GreyBeardedGeek

Answer (score 0):

change in these lines:

1. `<script type='text/javascript' src="script.js"></script>`
2. `alert('clickity-click');`

Comment: I think this does not matter. :)

Comment: Wait. Is it because the page is originated from another page?

Comment: you would need to define the function as global. here's a helpful link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335069/calling-a-javascript-function-from-another-js-file

Comment: you need to add `window.onLoad` listener to wait for the page to load.

Comment: But I have multiple functions defined in the same way and they work without having to refresh the page. :(