# how to call a java script function from another java script file?

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling a javascript function from another .js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335069/calling-a-javascript-function-from-another-js-file)

i'm new to java scripts . And i just want to  know how to call java script function in one java script file from another ? 
call a function in temp.js from main.js

Comment: See this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335069/calling-a-javascript-function-from-another-js-file

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is include both JavaScript files on the page. Assuming both functions are declared at the `window` level, they'll all be call-able from one another.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the files with the javascript code is with in the html document and you're able to call any functions located in any file from one file to another.

Comment: Your answer answers the question on "how to call from one file a function located in another" by saying basically: "make sure you are able to call functions in one file from another file". Obviously worth a downvote.