# Access function in another js file with $(document).ready(function()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

According to this post [Click here to see the referred post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335069/calling-a-javascript-function-from-another-js-file)

I tried to get access to a function which is defined in another .js file following the post instruction. However, I still have a problem. See my code below:

**sildemenu.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var window.slideMenu=function(){
        //do something here 
    }();
});
```

**control.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#foo').on('click', function() {
         window.slideMenu();
    });
});
```

I got the error "Object [object Window] has no method 'sildeMenu' ".
I am very new in programming. Please give me a mercy.

Comment: Execution of `sildemenu.js` fails because `var window.slideMenu` is a syntax error (and the issue gdoron mentions). Drop the `var`. I recommend to read http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners.

Comment: If you read the linked question/answer properly, you will see that there are no `()` after the function definition and no `var` before `window....`.

Answer (score 1):

You try to define a complex variable, (which is impossible this way) instead of assign a value to the global object- `window`.

```
  var window.slideMenu=function(){
//^^^ Get rid of this
    //do something here 
  }();
 //^^  and remove this
```

And get rid of the `var`
**Fixed code:**

```
window.slideMenu=function(){
    //do something here 
};
```

Comment: I did apply your Fixed code, however, I still got the same error. It seems like `slidemenu.js` is fine but the error comes from `control.js`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of window object just write:

**sildemenu.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    slideMenu=function(){
      //Do your stuff here!
    };
});
```

**control.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#foo').on('click', function() {
         slideMenu();
    });
});
```